# img dentro de div en html5

Tags: html, css, div, img

necesito ayuda de alguien q pueda decirme como logro centrar una imagen dentro de un div, para poder aprovechar todo el espacio de este, algo tan simple me esta volviendo loco. He encontrado varias respuestas por aqui pero ninguna me acaba de servir. Gracias.

```css
div.logodiv {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  /*line-height:60px;
 margin:0px auto;*/
  text-align: center;
}

div.logodiv img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logodiv">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  </a>
</div>
```

[image: logo dentro del div]

Comment: prueba agregando `w-100` y `h-100` a la etiqueta `a`

Comment: Según tu código no lo puedes lograr si usas ``width: 100%;`` y
``height: 100%;`` en la img. Basta con eliminar esto y no importa cuantos pixeles de ancho agregues a ``logodiv`` ya que tienes el img dentro de un ancla ``<a>`` y con la propiedad ``text-align:center;`` se centrara automáticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en la que solucione tu error fue haciendo que la etiqueta `<a>` contenga tanto al div, como a la imagen. Y no solo a la imagen como es en tu caso.

Prueba con el codigo que te estoy dejando abajo. En lugar de `href=""` en la etiqueta `<a>`, podrias poner tu `href="index.html"`.

Si no es lo que necesitas, intenta especificar un poco mas porfavor asi te puedo ayudar

```css
.container{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/90/90/"/>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: esta me funcionó de 10, gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, podrias marcar la respuesta como que resolvió tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Para centrar verticalmente hay varias maneras de hacerlo, `vertical-align` funciona para contenidos en table, por eso debes de agregar la propiedad `display` con el valor `table` al componente padre que en este caso es un div, y agrega el valor `table-cell` a el componente hijo que en este caso no es `img` sino `a` ya que es `a` quien es hijo de div, te dejo un ejemplo con bordes para apreciar mas el resultado:

```css
div.logodiv {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display: table;
}

div.logodiv img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
  
  a{
   display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="logodiv">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="https://articles-images.sftcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/04/image-06-100x100.png" alt="logo" />
  </a>
</div>
```

**Edit**:Si usas largo y ancho en porcentaje, no utilices el 100% ya que el componente hijo abarcara todo el espacio del componente padre y no se apreciara el centrado

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código en el css, justo en el div que contiene al logo:

```
justify-content:center;
```